# Update Table from a different page, using JQuery asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update a table column, specific to one row, ID=ID, Name=Name, etc. However, I can't figure out a way to get this done. I need to pull the name from the previous page and update their "Prize" from the second page. Highly Frustrating and probably simple. Any help would be appreciated!!

**UPDATE**

I have not gotten this wo work, but I found somewhere else that adding a location to retireve the parameters from would work, it did not.So to rephrase. In the first page people enter their info and it gets thrown to a DB. On the second page they spin a wheel and win a prize. I need to get that prize and have it inserted in that persons row.

View Side 1st Page, where people enter information.

```
<%@ Page Title="About" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="About.aspx.cs"
Inherits="WebApplication3.About" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"
runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"
ConnectionString="StateFairConnectionString" UpdateCommand="sp.SFLeads"
UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="name" placeholder="Name"
required="required"/>
<br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="email" placeholder="Email Address"
required="required"/>
<br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="phone" placeholder="Phone Number"
required="required"/>
<br />
<asp:radiobuttonlist runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
ID="interest" OnSelectedIndexChanged="interest_SelectedIndexChanged"
AutoPostBack="true" required="required">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Yes">&nbsp;Yes &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="No">&nbsp;No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:radiobuttonlist>


<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" ID="age" placeholder="--Select One--" Visible="false">
    <asp:ListItem>--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Under 13 Years</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>13-18 Years</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>18-25 Years</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>26-35 Years</asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submitbutton"
Text="Submit"OnClick="submitbutton_Click"/>
```

Code-Behind from first Page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["name"] = name.Text;
    }

    protected void interest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (interest.SelectedValue == "Yes")
        {
            age.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            age.Visible = false;
        }

    }

    protected void submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = ("ConnectionString");
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StateFair";
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "StateFair");
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        System.Data.DataRow drow = ds.Tables["StateFair"].NewRow();
        drow["Name"] = name.Text;
        drow["Phone"] = phone.Text;
        drow["Age"] = age.SelectedValue;
        drow["Interested"] = interest.SelectedValue;
        ds.Tables["StateFair"].Rows.Add(drow);
        da.Update(ds, "StateFair");


        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

}
}
```

View Side of things 2nd Page

```
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/WebForms/jquery.rotate.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
                var rotation = function () {
                    $("#wheel").rotate({
                        angle: 0,
                        animateTo: 360,
                        duration: 0,

                        callback: rotation,
                        easing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
                            return c * (t / d) + b;
                        },
                        bind: {
                            click: function () {
                                $(this).stopRotate();
                                var angle = $(this).getRotateAngle();
                                var shirt = "Shirt";
                                var hat = "Hat";
                                var pencil = "Pencil";
                                var book = "Schulz Book";
                                var less = "Free Lesson";
                                var kit = "Free Art Kit";
                                var tsq = "T-Square";

                                //if the wheel stop between angle 0-20 degrees and between 180.1-200 degrees win a Shirt

                                if (angle >= 0 && angle <= 20) { alert("You won a " + shirt);  $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Shirt"); }
                                else if (angle >= 180.1 && angle <= 200) { alert("You won a " + shirt); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Shirt"); }

                                    //if the wheel stops between 40.1-60, 100.1-120, 160.1-180, 260.1-280, 340.1-360 degrees; win a T-Square

                                else if (angle >= 40.1 && angle <= 60) { alert("You have won a " + tsq); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("T-Square"); }
                                else if (angle >= 100.1 && angle <= 120) { alert("You have won a " + tsq); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("T-Square"); }
                                else if (angle >= 160.1 && angle <= 180) { alert("You have won a " + tsq); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("T-Square"); }
                                else if (angle >= 260.1 && angle <= 280) { alert("You have won a " + tsq); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("T-Square"); }
                                else if (angle >= 340.1 && angle <= 360) { alert("You have won a " + tsq); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("T-Square"); }

                                    //if wheel stops between 20.1-40, 60.1-80, 120.1-140, 200.1-220, 240.1-260; win a Pencil

                                else if (angle >= 20.1 && angle <= 40) { alert("Sorry you are not a winner"); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Not a Winner"); }
                                else if (angle >= 60.1 && angle <= 80) { alert("Sorry you are not a winner"); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Not a Winner"); }
                                else if (angle >= 120.1 && angle <= 140) { alert("Sorry you are not a winner"); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Not a Winner"); }
                                else if (angle >= 200.1 && angle <= 220) { alert("Sorry you are not a winner"); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Not a Winner"); }
                                else if (angle >= 240.1 && angle <= 260) { alert("Sorry you are not a winner"); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Not a Winner"); }

                                    //if wheel stops between 140.1-160, 320.1-340; win a Hat

                                else if (angle >= 140.1 && angle <= 160) { alert("You have won a " + hat); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Draw Me Hat"); }
                                else if (angle >= 320.1 && angle <= 340) { alert("You have won a " + hat); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Draw Me Hat"); }

                                    //if wheel stops between 80.1-100; win a Free Lesson

                                else if (angle >= 80.1 && angle <= 100) { alert("You have won a " + less); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Free Lesson"); }

                                    //if wheel stops between 220.1-240; win a Schulz Book

                                else if (angle >= 220.1 && angle <= 240) { alert("You have won a " + book); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Schulz Book"); }

                                    //if wheel stops between 280.1-300; win a Free Art Kit

                                else if (angle >= 280.1 && angle <= 300) { alert("You have won a " + kit); $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val("Free Art Kit"); }

                                $(function () {
                                    var winner = $("#<%=sPrize.ClientID%>").val();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "Default.aspx/SavePrize",
                                        data:  winner,
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function (response) {
                                            alert("Prize has been added successfully.");
                                            window.location.reload();
                                        }
                                    });
                                    return false;
                                }
                            )}
                        }}
                    )}
        rotation();    
});



</script>




<center>

<asp:Label runat="server" id="dateTime"></asp:Label>
    <br />

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1" Text="" CssClass="label1"/>          <%-- Label to announce name --%>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="sPrize"></asp:TextBox>


    <br />
    |
    <br />
    <img src="Content/Wheel1.png" id="wheel" width="300"/>      <%-- The Wheel to spin --%>

    </center>





<hr />

<asp:GridView ID="gvUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2"

HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2">

<Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />

    <asp:BoundField DataField="Prize" HeaderText="Prize" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>




</asp:Content>
```

code-behind from 2nd Page.

```
    [WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public void SavePrize(Winner winner)
{

    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
    cnn.ConnectionString = ("ConnectionString");
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE StateFair SET Prize=@Prize WHERE Name=@Name";

    //set parameter for the prize to input
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Prize", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@Prize"].Value = sPrize.Text;

    // set the name parameter as to where the prize will go
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = (string)(Session["name"]);

    cmd.Connection = cnn;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prize", winner);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnn.Close();
        }    public class Winner
    {
    public string Prize { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What part of it are you stuck on?   Are you getting an error?

Comment: Your title says Update but the only SQL in this code is an `INSERT` statement.  Are you forgetting something?

Comment: @TabAlleman I am not getting an error, I am simply not able to get it into the column in which the previous page inserted user info.

Comment: @TTeeple I thought that all I would need is an Insert statement however, I feel that there is something missing due to not being able to select where to put the data within the database, specifically which user.

Comment: I think you need to add a lot more detail to your question.   It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, and what part of it is causing you trouble.